# Unexpected behaviour of paste() inside glue()

Tags: r

`paste(x, collapse = ',')` returns a string of length 1. However this is not the case when it is evaluated within  a `glue()` call. The help page of glue states clearly that "Expressions enclosed by braces will be evaluated as R code. " so I am a bit puzzled by this:

```
require(glue)

x = 1:3
y = paste(x, collapse = ',')

o1 = glue('{y}')
length(o1) #1

o2 = glue('{ paste(x, collapse = ',') }')
length(o2) #3
```

Why does o2 have a length of 3 instead of 1?

Answer (score 2):

Because you mixed ` instead of using two kinds of quotes `"`.

Instead use :

```
o2 = glue('{ paste(x, collapse = ",") }')
length(o2)
```

Comment: or escape them : `glue('{ paste(x, collapse = \',\') }')`